# How to disable pagination indicately first page, last page & indicately previous page, next page in Laravel

Tags: javascript, html, css, laravel

Actually, I am trying to make pagination disable handler so that if I stay on the number 1 page the first page & the previous page will be disabled and the next page & last page will remain able to clickable, so as to, I can go next page and last page. In the same way, if I stay on the last page the next page & last page will be disabled and the previous page & first page will remain able to clickable. so as I can go to the previous page and the first page. How can I manage this system?

> Pagination view design:

The first **button** is the **first page**, the **second button** is the **previous page** the third one is an **input area** for pagination number which the number of pages I want to go, the fourth **button** is the **next page**, the fifth **button** is the **last page**.

[image]

> **Function is here:**

```html
public function index(){

    $master_product_list = EbayMasterProduct::with('variationProducts')->orderByDesc('id')->paginate(50);
    $master_decode_product_list = json_decode(json_encode($master_product_list));

 return view('ebay.master_product.master_product_list',compact('master_product_list','master_decode_product_list'));
        }
```

**Here is my pagination view code:**

```html
<div class="pagination-area">
  <form action="{{url('pagination-all')}}" method="post">
      @csrf
      <div class="datatable-pages d-flex align-items-center">
          <span class="displaying-num">  {{$master_product_list->total()}} items</span>
          <span class="pagination-links d-flex">
              <a class="first-page btn" href="{{$master_decode_product_list->first_page_url}}" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="First Page">
                  <span class="screen-reader-text d-none">First page</span>
                  <span aria-hidden="true">«</span>
              </a>
              <a class="prev-page btn" href="{{$master_decode_product_list->prev_page_url}}" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Previous Page">
                  <span class="screen-reader-text d-none">Previous page</span>
                  <span aria-hidden="true">‹</span>
              </a>
              <span class="paging-input d-flex align-items-center">
                  <label for="current-page-selector" class="screen-reader-text d-none">Current Page</label>
                  <input class="current-page" id="current-page-selector" type="text" name="paged" value="{{$master_decode_product_list->current_page}}" size="3" aria-describedby="table-paging">
                  <span class="datatable-paging-text d-flex">of<span class="total-pages">{{$master_decode_product_list->last_page}}</span></span>
                  <input type="hidden" name="route_name" value="ebay-master-product-list">
              </span>
              <a class="next-page btn" href="{{$master_decode_product_list->next_page_url}}" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Next Page">
                  <span class="screen-reader-text d-none">Next page</span>
                  <span aria-hidden="true">›</span>
              </a>
              <a class="last-page btn" href="{{$master_decode_product_list->last_page_url}}" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Last Page">
                  <span class="screen-reader-text d-none">Last page</span>
                  <span aria-hidden="true">»</span>
              </a>
          </span>
      </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take a look at the available paginator methods in the documentation.
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/pagination#paginator-instance-methods

Specifically, you will need these:

```php
$paginator->currentPage(); // get the current page number
$paginator->lastPage();    // get the page number of the last available page
```

If you want to remove the buttons, your code would look something like this:

```html
<div class="pagination-area">

    // ...

    @if ($master_product_list->currentPage() > 1)        
        // first and previous buttons
    @endif

    // ...

    @if ($master_product_list->currentPage() !== $master_product_list->lastPage())
        // last and next buttons
    @endif

    // ...
  
</div>
```

If you only want to disable the buttons, you could add a `disabled` class:

```html
<a class="first-page btn {{ $master_product_list->currentPage() > 1 ? '' : 'disabled' }}">
    // ...
</a>
```